# Nautilus Preference won't save in root

Tags: nautilus

My nautilus file manager won't save any preference setting everytime I run it via root, run `sudo nautilus` the icons views are big and sort files is set by default.

I want to force save my preference for root nautilus so everytime I din't have to click icons smaller/sort files/etc.

please reply thank you.

Answer (score 0):

It is an extremely bad idea to run graphical applications with the `sudo` command.

For these scarce moments where you need to use the graphical file manager with root permissions, do it the supported way. Run

```
nautilus admin:///
```

to run nautilus in the system root folder and be able to manage files with root permissions. The first time, you need to provide your password twice in a row.

This immediately solves your problem. Nautilus will act and feel as usual, and adopt/remember your daily user settings. In fact, you are not running nautilus as root, you only give it the possibility to do things for which you need to be root.

Close such instance of nautilus as soon as possible. You can directly open in a location where you need to work by providing the path name, e.g.

```
nautilus admin:///usr/share/applications
```